# Github API: Possible to set reporter of issue to another user when creating issue?

Tags: github, github-api

I've been tasked with importing a bunch of JIRA issues and their associated comments into Github issues.

Using the Github v3 API, is it possible to set the person who opened the issue to another user in our Github organization/team other than my authenticated self when I create the issue?  I'd like the JIRA reporters (in JIRA language the reporter is the  one who opened the issue) of the issues to be the one listed as the creators of the issues on Github.

Also, is it possible to attribute comments to other users in the organization when I create the comments programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to use the feature which is available in GitHub Enterprise edition only. So, if your repository is hosted on github.com, the answer is no, it's not possible without asking every user to provide you with [their personal api tokens](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens).

If you're lucky enough to be GH Enterprise user you can do that via [Impersonation oauth tokens](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.3/v3/users/administration/#create-an-impersonation-oauth-token)

Make a request:

```
POST /admin/users/:username/authorizations
```

And use the token to perform other actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you create an application using the [OAuth Authorizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/). Each user you want to impersonate would have to grant permissions in order for this to work.

Alternately, you could automatically assign the Issue to the correct person, or add an @-mention at the bottom of the Issue text to point out who the creator of the original issue was.